# Serial packets get corrupted or read midline - python RS-232

Tags: python, serial-port

OK. I am at a loss. I am trying to get my serial reading to stay in line and not get corrupted... The packets of information come in every 5 seconds as per my read protocol, however it seems as though when I retrieve from serial it gets the info 'mid-packet' so my new line in a CSV file is off  ... I presume it has something to do with my serial code ... how can i make sure that my packets are read properly?? (starting with their first character [the date] and ending with /n)

```
 #Serial Reading    
    ser = serial.Serial(port='COM4', baudrate=9600, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, timeout=None, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False, interCharTimeout=0.05)   
    out = ser.readline()
    ser.flushInput() 
    time.sleep(0.5)
    ser.inWaiting()
    out += ser.readline()
    reading = str(out)
    ser.close()
```